# How to rank users?

Tags: algorithms, distance-functions

I have a list of movies ranked out of 5 based on their income.

I have users ranking the same movies. Not all users rank all movies.

How can I find out which users have the best correlation between what they ranked and what the income of the movie was?

Comment: It will depend on your definition of the "best" correlation.

Comment: What was the point of turing movies' income into a 5-level ordinal ranking? That throws away a lot of information.

Comment: Moonwalker: We want to rank the users according to who will be the best at predicting the income of future movies.